# How to remove text from a folder name after a certain word

Tags: delete, text, rename

Need assistance trying to write a script/command that will clear text on a directory after a certain word, in this example download. Thought about using a for i statement but have had no luck.

Example

Song Band - Song Name download 9038450985934853434

Music List download dkjge3j6lk45j45756567

Video Chart download 4k645jel43k5yk574yryryrrtyryrryryrt

Trying to make it where it would clear the word download and everything else to the right to look like this

Song Band - Song Name

Music List

Video Chart

Comment: This looks like a job for `cut`. See `man cut`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code you need plus some test data you don't need:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: truncate-dname
# PATH: $HOME/askubuntu/
# DESC: Answer for: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249771/how-to-remove-text-from-a-folder-name-after-a-certain-word/1249785#1249785
# DATE: June 12, 2020

echo ==============  CREATE TEST DATA  ==================
mkdir -p dnames
cd dnames
mkdir -p "Song Band - Song Name download 9038450985934853434"
mkdir -p "Music List download dkjge3j6lk45j45756567"
mkdir -p "Video Chart download 4k645jel43k5yk574yryryrrtyryrryryrt"
ls

echo ==============  RENAME DIRECTORIES  ================
for old_name in ./*
do
    new_name="${old_name% download*}"
    mv -v "$old_name" "$new_name"
done

echo ==============  DELETE TEST DATA  ==================
ls
cd ..
rm -rf dnames
```

When you run the script you get this:

```bash
$ truncate-dname
============== CREATE TEST DATA ==================
Music List download dkjge3j6lk45j45756567
Song Band - Song Name download 9038450985934853434
Video Chart download 4k645jel43k5yk574yryryrrtyryrryryrt
============== RENAME DIRECTORIES ================
'./Music List download dkjge3j6lk45j45756567' -> './Music List'
'./Song Band - Song Name download 9038450985934853434' -> './Song Band - Song Name'
'./Video Chart download 4k645jel43k5yk574yryryrrtyryrryryrt' -> './Video Chart'
============== DELETE TEST DATA ==================
Music List  Song Band - Song Name  Video Chart
```

---

The key operation you want is to extract sub-string within string before a search string. For example:

```bash
$ a="Song Band - Song Name download 9038450985934853434"

$ b="${a% download*}"

$ echo $b
Song Band - Song Name
```

This process is a little tricky if the word "download" appears in the song title so it's in the filename twice:

```bash
$ c="People keep downloading my songs download 9038465489643541"

$ d="${c%% download*}"

$ echo $d
People keep

$ d="${c% download*}"

$ echo $d
People keep downloading my songs
```

When you have two `%%` it deletes everything after the first "download" occurrence which you don't want. So in this case you want to just use a single `%` so the last "download" is the cut off point.

There is also the `#` operation which searches in the opposite direction you definitely don't want:

```bash
$ c="People keep downloading my songs download 9038465489643541"

$ e="${c##* download}"

$ echo $e
9038465489643541

$ e="${c#* download}"

$ echo $e
ing my songs download 9038465489643541
```

Here is a [thorough reference](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner, your script works great if there's a common name, in my example download. Would it still work if it had different names, like document, download, homepage, etc.